# How to calculate birthdays in HIVE/HUE?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hue

I am querying in hue/hive and want to get the list of customers who are turning 64 years + 30 in the current month or the next month. The database has the DOB in yyyy-mm-dd format. How can I achieve this? Please help thanks.

This is what I have so far

SELECT
       floor(datediff(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),TO_DATE(BIRTH_DT))/365) AS age
   FROM table
where (floor(datediff(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),TO_DATE(BIRTH_DT))/365) >= 64)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would use:

```
  SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())), dob) / 365.25)>=64
```

Hope this helps.